# uniswap transaction issue. unable to locate txnhash

Tags: uniswap

I am trying to exhange one token for the other however the transaction is not going through, on etherscan when i go to view the transaction overview it states "sorry, we are unable to locate this txnhash" and the transaction is just stuck

Answer (score 0):

If the transaction is not found in Etherscan, my guess is that the transaction is not broadcast to the network. So you should check whether your client is fully synchronized with the network.